# Extracting feature detail from SelectPercentile: Column names and respective scores

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I'm trying to match features scores with columns names using a `Pipeline` with `SelectPercentile` and `RandomForestClassifier`.

From my initial EDA, the feature importance analysis seems to make sense. Nevertheless I'm not sure if I've done it correctly.

My main concern is that I'm getting the original `DataFrame` column Index ids (to get to know the original column names) via `SelectPercentile.scores_` and assuming these features are aligned (when ordered) with `RandomForestClassifier.feature_importances_`

I haven't seen this done anywhere. Am I doing it right?

My Pipeline:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectPercentile, f_classif
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

# NOTE: Make sure that the outcome column is labeled 'target' in the data file
tpot_data = df_delays_final_ml
features = tpot_data.drop('class', axis=1)
training_features, testing_features, training_target, testing_target = \
            train_test_split(features, tpot_data['class'], random_state=None)

# Average CV score on the training set was: 0.9131840089838837
exported_pipeline = make_pipeline(
    SelectPercentile(score_func=f_classif, percentile=56),
    RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=False, criterion="entropy", max_features=0.9000000000000001, min_samples_leaf=9, min_samples_split=9, n_estimators=100)
)

exported_pipeline.fit(training_features, training_target)
results = exported_pipeline.predict(testing_features)
```

The Feature analysis bit:

```
nbr_of_features = exported_pipeline.named_steps['selectpercentile'].get_support().sum()

top_features = [tpot_data.columns.tolist()[i] for i in np.argsort(exported_pipeline.named_steps['selectpercentile'].scores_)[::-1]][0:nbr_of_features]

importances = exported_pipeline.named_steps['randomforestclassifier'].feature_importances_
std = np.std([tree.feature_importances_ for tree in exported_pipeline.named_steps['randomforestclassifier'].estimators_], axis=0)
indices = np.argsort(importances)[::-1]
col_arr = []

for f in range(nbr_of_features):
    col_name = top_features[f]
    col_arr.insert(len(col_arr), col_name)
    print("%d. feature %d (%f) [%s]" % (f + 1, indices[f], importances[indices[f]], col_name))

plt.figure(figsize=(19, 6))
plt.title("Feature importances")
plt.bar(range(nbr_of_features), importances[indices], color="r", yerr=std[indices], align="center")
plt.xticks(range(nbr_of_features), col_arr, rotation=45)
plt.xlim([-1, 9])
plt.show()
```

And the result:

> 1. feature 0 (0.291853) [dew_point_celsius]
> 2. feature 3 (0.272066) [air_temperature_celcius]
> 3. feature 1 (0.114740) [minute_of_day]
> 4. feature 2 (0.084233) [course]
> 5. feature 5 (0.079613) [business_weekday]
> 6. feature 8 (0.069989) [precipitation_mm]
> 7. feature 6 (0.041912) [wind_gusts_10m_ms]
> 8. feature 7 (0.037132) [line_number]
> 9. feature 4 (0.008462) [wind_speed_10m_ms]

[image]

Comment: your code seems fine.

Comment: The assumption about the meaning and relation of `SelectPercentile.scores_` and `RandomForestClassifier.feature_importances_` is correct? There are features for which the importance is quite close. I'm afraid I might be mixing features.